# Function that converts number of matches to winning prize

Tags: c++, arrays, function, for-loop

I am creating a lottery program that generates a ticket of 5 random numbers, between 1-36. The user can choose how many tickets he wants, which is my for loop in main. I completed most of the code, but I am having issues with creating a function that converts the number of matches found to prize winnings in an array that will combine the winnings after the for loop ends. Everything works fine, but I'm having trouble understanding how I can store winnings from the for loop into another array so I can combine the total of winnings. Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

const int ARRAY_SIZE = 5; //size of the array

//function prototypes
void generateWinning (int [], int);
void genTicket(int[], int);
void bubbleSort(int [], int);
void findMatch(int [], int [], int[]);
void printArray(int [], int);
void printWinning(int);

int main()
{
srand( time(NULL) );

int numTickets, j;

int totalWinnings[4]={0,0,0,0};
int lottery[ARRAY_SIZE]; //holds winning lottery
int user[ARRAY_SIZE]; //holds users number of ticks

cout << "Enter number of tickets: ";
cin >> numTickets;
   generateWinning (lottery, ARRAY_SIZE); //generate winning tickets, then 
//display
   printArray(lottery, ARRAY_SIZE);
   for( int i=0; i < numTickets; i++)//loop amount of times user chooses tickets
        {
        genTicket(user, ARRAY_SIZE);//generate random numbers without duplicates
        bubbleSort(user, ARRAY_SIZE);//sort list of array sorted.
        printArray(user, ARRAY_SIZE); //print results.
        findMatch(lottery,user, totalWinnings);//find matches then store 
//them into totalWinning Array

        }
printArray(totalWinnings, 4);
   //j=0;
   //int total = totalWinnings[j] + totalWinnings[j+1] + totalWinnings[j+2] 
+ totalWinnings[j+3];

  //cout << "You Total Prize Amount = "<< "$" << total <<endl;

        return 0;
}
void printArray(int arr[], int size)
{
        int i;
        for (i=0; i < size; i++)
        {
           printf("%d", arr[i]);
           printf(" ");
        }
        cout << endl;
}
void generateWinning(int lottery[], int ARRAY_SIZE)
{
        cout << "Winner ";
        int index =0;
        int lotteryPool[36];
        for(int x = 0; x<36; x=x+1)
        {
        lotteryPool[x]=x+1;
        }
        random_shuffle(&lotteryPool[0], &lotteryPool[35]);
        while (index < ARRAY_SIZE)
        {
          lottery[index] = lotteryPool[index];
          index++;
        }
        bubbleSort(lottery,ARRAY_SIZE);
}
void genTicket(int arr[], int ARRAY_SIZE)
{
        int index=0;
        int lotteryPool[36];
        for (int x=0; x<36; x=x+1)
        {
        lotteryPool[x]= x+1;
        }
        random_shuffle(&lotteryPool[0], &lotteryPool[35]);
        while (index < ARRAY_SIZE)
        {
        arr[index] = lotteryPool[index];
        index++;
        }
}

void bubbleSort(int user[], int ARRAY_SIZE)
{
        int i, j, temp;
        for (i=1; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i)
        {
           for(j=0; j<(ARRAY_SIZE-i); ++j)
           {
              if (user[j] > user[j+1])
              {
              temp = user[j];
              user[j]=user[j+1];
              user[j+1] = temp;
              }
           }
        }
}
void findMatch(int user[], int lottery[], int winning[])
{
        int index, temp;
        int matches = 0;
        for(int index = 0; index < ARRAY_SIZE; index++)
        {
           for(int temp =0; temp < ARRAY_SIZE; temp++)
           {
                  if(lottery[index]==user[temp])
                  {
                matches++;
              }
              else
              {
              cout <<"";
              }
           }
        }
        cout << matches << endl;
        int i;
           if (matches == 2)
           {
           winning[i]=1;
           }
           else if (matches == 3)
           {
           winning[i]=10;
           }
           else if(matches == 4)
           {
     winning[i]=500;
           }
           else if (matches = 5)
           {
           winning[i]=25000;
           }


}


This is my output:
Enter number of tickets: 5
Winner 2 9 14 30 33
7 11 14 16 29
1
10 14 33 34 35
2
1 8 12 25 34
1
6 13 25 28 33
1
2 3 11 13 26
1
0 0 0 0 //why is this not storing match that equal prize?
```

Comment: you are using `i` uninitialized in `winning[i]=1;`. thats undefined behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are invoking undefined behaviour in this part of your code:

```
       // in findMatch
       int i; // i is uninitialized
       if (matches == 2)
       {
           winning[i]=1; // using i as an array index results in undefined behavior
       }
       else if (matches == 3)
       {
           winning[i]=10;
       }
       else if(matches == 4)
       {
          winning[i]=500;
       }
       //else if (matches = 5) // typo in the operator here 
       else if (matches == 5)
       {
          winning[i]=25000;
       }
```

To fix this, just add `i` as a parameter to your function and get rid of the `int i;` in findMatch:

```
void findMatch(int user[], int lottery[], int winning[], int i)
{ ... }
```

Comment: When I make those changes, my output at the end becomes 

    25000 25000 25000 25000 stored in the array when the matches are different

Comment: @MRxBEYOND ```else if (matches = 5)``` will always evaluate to true and thus cause 25000 to be written into your array each time.

Comment: Okay, so what should I use instead if it's always going to return true?

Comment: @MRxBEYOND The issue is you are **assigning** 5 to ```matches``` not **comparing** it with 5. You need to use the correct operator: ```else if (matches == 5)```

Comment: @MRxBEYOND *When I make those changes* -- Those changes were required.  Whether that fixes every single error is a different story.  Ask another question, or try to figure out the rest of the faulty code and why it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: I added, if else statements for matches if it equals 0 or 1 and it's actually working now, thanks @nick !